# Change a field across many MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, myisam

Scenario: I have users that want to be able to change their username (unfortunately I didn't think about adding this functionality when I started the site), but the MySQL database has 110 tables.

Am I going to have to just make a script that executes 110 queries to update the username in each table (and remember to update the script when I add new tables), or is there a way to link the fields in all of the tables, so updating the username in one table updates it in all of the others?

Comment: Updating a key over multiple tables is a bad idea. You might want to take this opportunity to restructure your database to add an autoincrement integer primary key for all your users and use that as your foreign key instead of the username. It's a big change but once it's done, you won't regret it. You'll probably even get better performance and less disk usage as a bonus.

Comment: I have an auto increment integer key for each user, the userid, but all of the other tables reference the username, otherwise it would be a non-issue and I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Okay well it is looking like this won't be possible and I'll just have to make a bunch of queries.  I have to use MyISAM and switching to using the userid instead of the username is not an option considering the site is live.

Comment: Note that you're potentially asking for trouble in that case. MyISAM is not transactional, so if the server crashes in the middle of your renaming process, you can end up with only half of the tables updated, and you can't prevent it. If you switched to using the ID for foreign keys, you wouldn't have that problem.

Comment: @James Simpson. It is possible to make the modifications require to your datastructure to the live database, it just is difficult to get it right first time. You first need to provide both columns in your database (foreign key with username and foreign key with id), then switch the code over to use the new foreign keys, and finally delete the old columns. Practice first on your test system and test database, and save every DB modification you do in scripts so you are sure it is repeatable. (You do have a test system, right?)

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want the adrenaline rush of modifying the production system which its running, just take the system down for a few hours while you upgrade it. I'm sure your users will survive. Again, make sure your upgrade scripts have been tested on a test system first.

Comment: Right, but that will just be a big mess to deal with considering there are over 100,000 lines of code that would have to be updated.  It isn't worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup the tables to do CASCADING updates.

This is accomplished by using foreign keys and the `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Here is a good article on it: http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2004/10/hey_sql_fans_check_out_foreign.html

And the official MySQL page:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

**UNFORTUNATELY this is for InnoDB only, so you would have to switch the tables over.**

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using the username as your primary key, since you've seen the need to do this. Change your table structure to use an auto_increment ID as the primary key instead of usernames, and refer to the ID from the other tables, rather than the name directly. This prevents duplication of the username across tables and lets you change a username by only updating a single table.

Note that you may want to keep a UNIQUE index on the username itself to prevent duplicates: currently, you get that for "free" by using the name as the PK, and you can continue to let the DB manage it by making a new index.

Comment: In a reply to my comment he said he he has an autoincrement id for every user, and I think that it is also his primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreign key constraints with [ON UPDATE CASCADE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) to automatically update foreign keys when they are modified (InnoDB only).

But it would be better not to use the username as a foreign key. You should normally use a [surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key) as a foreign key so that this is not an issue.

Comment: This is for InnoDB tables only, it has not been implemented in MyISAM